# Multiple SendDTMF extension in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Good day, I need type extension after dial, I wrote a macros and use it in Dial command, for example:

```
Dial(Local/123123@outbound-allroutes,,M(sendnum^5^123)

[macro-sendnum]
exten => s,1,Wait(${ARG1})
exten => s,n,SendDTMF(${ARG2})
```

But sometimes I need type several ext. numbers, how can I do that?

I guessed pass more params in macros at first param is count of IVR steps, and other params are options for steps then in macros process those params in loop, for example:

```
Dial(Local/123123@outbound-allroutes,,M(sendnum^2^5^2010^6^123)
```

and macros for this:

```
macro-sendnum]
exten => s,1,Set(TIMES=${ARG1})
exten => s,n,Set(i=0})
exten => s,n,While($[${i} < ${TIMES}])
exten => s,n,Set(i=$[ ${i} + 1 ])
exten => s,n,Wait(${ARG$[${i} + 1]})
exten => s,n,SendDTMF(${ARG$[${i} + 2]})
exten => s,n,EndWhile
```

But that doesn't work. Could you please help me? Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad endgish.

Answer (score 0):

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show application SendDTMF 

  -= Info about application 'SendDTMF' =- 

[Synopsis]
Sends arbitrary DTMF digits 

[Description]
It will send all digits or terminate if it encounters an error.

[Syntax]
SendDTMF(digits[,timeout_ms[,duration_ms[,channel]]])

[Arguments]
digits
    List of digits 0-9,*#,a-d,A-D to send also w for a half second pause,
    and f or F for a flash-hook if the channel supports flash-hook.
timeout_ms
    Amount of time to wait in ms between tones. (defaults to .25s)
duration_ms
    Duration of each digit
channel
    Channel where digits will be played
```

So you can use 'w' as pause.